# Compare execution model for exec() vs setTimeout in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, shell

I am just curious to understand the node.js internals. We have got a requirement to execute shell scripts and capture the output to a variable. We have found the following solution

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('pwd', (err, stdo, stde) => {
      if (err) return;
      // capture output .. it can grow later
      out = stdo;
});


setTimeout(() => console.log('test'), 3000);
```

`.exec` and `setTimeout` runs asynchronously. However, **setTimeout** does not create a separate process or thread (it uses libuv or V8 async API) where these async calls are handled by system pool (since it would not create process or thread for every setTimeout which makes blazing fast and less memory)

Now when I run **.exec**, We are using `child_process` (that might spawn separate process), we are assuming that it would create a  `thread or process` at node.js level (like how we create threads in **Java and C#**). This takes some time to fork a process or thread and it also consumes process memory size.

So does `.exec` works similar to Java and C# threading? or does it run similar to setTimeout utilizing the V8 async API or libuv?

Put it short, If I run 1 million `setTimeouts`, the process will not be hanging ([demo shown by Ryan Dahl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I)). If I create 1 million `.exec()`, is behavior similar to setTimeouts or does it overblow with spawned processes and blew up the server? (I would try once I get access to, but I would really like to know the internal behavior as well instead of vaguely saying it blows off).
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Finally, is Node.js good choice of language for handling concurrent connections if we execute only shell scripts?

**Reference:**

https://zaiste.net/nodejs-child-process-spawn-exec-fork-async-await/

> mentions child_process module allows to create child processes in
>   Node.js.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

> Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell.

Comment: `exec` does create a new process *at the OS level*. It has nothing to do with threads within node.js.

Comment: @Bergi Just curious, if `exec` is not creating process, does it utilize V8 Async api, so running 1 million exec will not blow up system?

Comment: Running a million processes at the same time will blow up most operating systems.

Comment: I said "*exec does create a new process*"

Comment: @Bergi https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback it was mentioned "Spawns a shell then executes the command within that shell, " Spawning is not creating a process? just curios

Comment: I never said that it didn't. Yes, spawning a shell means creating a new process.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Thanks, I think I have understood. One last question so no matter what language we choose, since the shell always creates a process.  Does everyone other languages out there use a separate process for the shell?